# where can i find the massageID and tokenID for api call?

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, mobileconnect, marketingcloudapi

Good afternoon

I'm starting the configuration for an API call that returns email and sms data received by the customer in the marketing cloud

checking documentations I found this call here:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/getMessageContactDelivery.html

```
GET /sms/v1/messageContact/{messageId}/deliveries/{tokenId}
```

my difficulty now is where to find the tokenID and messageID data, I know that this information I will find in mobileconnect but not exactly where

can you help me?

Comment: I found out through the documentation about the messageID but not the other one: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_view_sms_message_tracking.htm&type=5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you already found the [messageID](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_view_sms_message_tracking.htm&type=5).

The TokenId is the Id returned by the API call when you send out an SMS using the POST [/sms/v1/messageContact/{id}/send](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/postMessageContactSend.html) API route

Response from this route will give you:

```
HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted
{
  "tokenId": "c21NCNSDN2sMMWM2miosdjEHH",
}
```

Comment: Is the call performed with the {id} that way and empty to have the return of the token?

/sms/v1/messageContact/{id}/send